# Como renderisar componentes Reactjs de manera asíncrona.

Tags: javascript, html5, reactjs

Como puedo renderisar componentes Reactjs de manera asíncrona.
Ejemplo :
ListaItems componente Padre
Items componenteHijo

A mi ComponenteListaItems envió 2000 registros, entonces realizo un map de cada uno y voy armando cada componente de Items.
al finalizar los 2000 registros, recién renderiso el componenteListaItems.

Lo que deseo saber es, cuando ya tenga un componente Items ya armado que me renderice y que no espere a los 2000 registros.

gracias, estaré atento a sus comentarios.

Comment: No entiendo, primero preguntas cómo senderizar de manera asíncrona y después preguntas por cómo hacerle para que no espere. Por favor ve a [edit] tu pregunta y aclara qué es lo que deseas y si es posible incluye un [mcve]. Con gusto veré si puedo ayudarte!

Answer (score 0):

La solucion son las listas virtuales. El concepto es simple:

**"Solo renderizamos lo que se ve"**

Y esta bien, porque vas a renderizar 2000 items si solo muestras 20 (1%) o en un mobil 5 (0.25%). queda claro el impacto en el rendimiento que esto significa.

Ahora bien, a modo de ejemplo nos imaginamos una lista de 2000 items y una *ventana* (items a mostrar) de 20, a medida que desplazamos la *ventana* vamos renderizando. algo asi como un slice:

```
const { list2k, windowSize } = this.props
// list2k es la lista de 2000 items y windowsSize = 20
const { currentIndex } this.state    
var listToRender = list2k.slice(currentIndex , windowSize);
.......
```

En react hay unos componentes llamados [react-virtualized](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/List) que hacen exactamente eso. Hay muchos ejemplo y documentacion sobre esto.

Cabe destacar que las listas virtuales existen tambien en otros lenguajes y contextos. por ejemplo las plantillas de calculo y es una alternativa a la paginación